# How to plot graph where the indexes are strings

Tags: python, pandas

I'm running with `python 3.7.6` and I have the following `dataframe`:

```
         col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4
GP           1      1      1      1
MIN          1      1      1      1
PTS          1      1      1      1
FGM          1      1      0      1
FGA          0      1      0      0
FG%          0      1      1      1
3P Made      0      1      1      0
AST          0      1      1      0
STL          0      1      0      0
BLK          0      1      1      0
TOV          0      0      1      0
```

I want to plot the `dataframe` as `scatter plot or other (dot's plot)` where:

X axis - dataframe indexes

Y axis - dataframe columns

points on the graph are according to the values from `dataframe` (1 - show on graph and 0 not)

How can I do it ?

Comment: a scatter plot in this case does not make much sense, you mostly use a scatter plot when you have to numeric series. Yours are categorical with binary.

Comment: Yes, I think what you want is something else. And how do you want to deal with the columns? Are then joined lines?

Comment: But try .replace(0, np.nan).plot(kind='bar')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure about scatter, but you can use `imshow` to display the binary values:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(df, cmap='gray')
ax.set_xticks(range(df.shape[1]))
ax.set_xticklabels(df.columns)

ax.set_yticks(range(df.shape[0]))
ax.set_yticklabels(df.index)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

---

**Update**: scatter also possible:

```
plt.scatter(*np.where(df.T))
plt.xticks(range(df.shape[1]), df.columns)
plt.yticks(range(df.shape[0]), df.index)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Here's the proof, scatter in this case does not make much sense.